# How to set dynamic initial values to django modelform field

Tags: python, django, forms, web

I'm kinda new to django, I need to set a dynamic initial value to my modelform field. I have a database field in my model name 'author' it has a foreignkey that connects it to the django user model. I need to automatically set this to the current user anytime a user fills in information into the form.
from what I gathered about this problem, I'd have to define an `__init__` function inside the MyHouseEditForm below, I'm new to django and all the examples I've seen a pretty confusing.

forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Myhouses

class MyHouseEditForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:        
        model = Myhouses        
        fields = ('author','name_of_accomodation', 'type_of_room', 'house_rent', 'availability', 'location', 'nearest_institution', 'description', 'image')
```

i need to set the value of 'author' to the current user anytime a user logs in.

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class Myhouses(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='author')
        Available = 'A'
        Not_Available = 'NA'
        Availability = (
            (Available, 'Available'),
            (Not_Available, 'Not_Available'),
        )
    name_of_accomodation = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type_of_room = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    house_rent = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    availability = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Availability, default=Available,)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    nearest_institution = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_of_accomodation
```

views.py

```py
@login_required
def addlisting(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = MyHouseEditForm(request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():    
            Houses = form.save(commit=False)
            Houses.save()
            return redirect('addlisting')           
    else:        
        form = MyHouseEditForm()  

    return render(request, 'houses/addlisting.html', {'form':form })
```

Comment: Looking at your code I guess that what you really need is to save a logged  in user into the `author` field upon the form save. If so, all you need is `Houses.author=request.user` before `Houses.save()`. Also you should change `User` to `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` in author field definition. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#reusable-apps-and-auth-user-model)

Answer (score 1):

No need to show author field in form. It would automatically populate with logged in user.

*request.user* gives you logged in user object. So, you may remove 'author' filed from forms field section and do this:

```
Houses = form.save(commit=False)
Houses.author = request.user
Houses.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this in the serializer.

I defined a custom create method like this:

```
class MyhousesSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['author'] = self.context['request'].user

        newhouse = Myhouses.objects.create(**validated_data)

        return newhouse
```

It shouldn't matter if you use a more regular model serializer.